# Make a Centered Horizontal Navigation

Tags: css, menu, navigation, alignment, center

On this website, http://usher1f.org/ , in mobile view or in a view when the browser is narrowed to 800 px width, the navigation sits off to the left.  How can I make the navigation be centered horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to center something using CSS is to set the width to some value, then set the left and right margins to be 'auto', in the case of your site, the following should be included in the #cssmenu CSS rules:

```
#cssmenu {
    width: 451px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for another question.  While this code did center the navigation, the issue is that when the browser width shrinks to below 451 pixels, the padding stays at 85px.  I tried to set the padding to 0, the navigation automatically justified to the right.  How can this be corrected?  Thank you!

Comment: I apologize again for another question, when I set the browser width to 800 px, the navigation bar is still not really placed center.  Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: Ok - I just finally figured out the problem.  Besides giving a specific width, I also needed to set the float to "none."  It's now looking great!  Now, this question is a little not related to this but I am wondering if anyone could assist.  In the desktop view, you can see a thin gray bottom border, but in mobile view or when you shrink the browser to below 800px, the gray line is gone. Any suggestions?

Comment: I figured out the border issue.  I'm all set!

Comment: I was away for a bit, great that you figured it all out!